# Did I use "only" appropriately in my sentence?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

> I was wondering if I have to **only** book appointment on Fridays for the rest of my treatment.

Is *only* used appropriately in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Your usage is understandable

> I was wondering if I **have to only** book appointment on Fridays for the rest of my treatment.

has the meaning you can only book appointments on Fridays, but better might be

> I was wondering if I **can only** book appointment**s** on Fridays for the rest of my treatment.

If what you mean is that your appointment can only *be on** Fridays, then

> I was wondering if I **can only** book appointment**s** **for** Fridays for the rest of my treatment.